# Javascript countdown timer can't set half past hour

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a countdown timer to count to a certain time everyday (monday to friday). So far everything works, except it can only be set to count to a certain hour (based on the 24 hour clock) without a half hour included. So for example, if I wanted to count to 4PM, I'd set `var target = 16;` but if I wanted 4:30 and I tried to set `var target = 1630;` it doesn't work. Unfortunately I don't have much experience with javascript, but I believe the problem is either with the way it's evaluating the target time using the `getHours` function but not sure where to take it from there.

```
if (document.getElementById('countdownTimer')) {
    pad = function(n, len) { // leading 0's
        var s = n.toString();
        return (new Array( (len - s.length + 1) ).join('0')) + s;
    };
    function countDown() {
        var now = new Date();
        if ( (now.getDay() >= 1) && (now.getDay() <= 5) ) { // Monday to Friday only
            var target = 15; // 15:00hrs is the cut-off point
            if (now.getHours() < target) { // don't do anything if we're past the cut-off point
                var hrs = (target - 1) - now.getHours();
                if (hrs < 0) hrs = 0;
                var mins = 59 - now.getMinutes();
                if (mins < 0) mins = 0;
                var secs = 59 - now.getSeconds();
                if (secs < 0) secs = 0;
                var str = pad(hrs, 2) + ':' + pad(mins, 2) + '.<small>' + pad(secs, 2) + '</small>';
                document.getElementById('countdownTimer').innerHTML = str;
            }
        }
    }
    var timerRunning = setInterval('countDown()', 1000);
}
```

Comment: [It doesn't work for me at all](http://jsfiddle.net/7H6vp/), even after removing the parenthesis in the setInterval that caused an error

Comment: If you say 'countdown' I'd think you'd get the day and time once and then set a Timeout to the target time.

Comment: Indeed. Instead of parsing strings over and over again, try using [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: for `4:30PM`. wouldn't you do a `var target = 16.5;` instead of `var target = 1630;` ?

Comment: @ZachSaucier I had to use a span class rather than div such as `<span id="countdownTimer">00:00.<small>00</small></span>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="daySensitiveCountdownTimer.js"></script>` with the script placed directly in the body, not in the head which might be why the js fiddle doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with considering another method, the following javascript will count down (in seconds) to any date in the future (and count up after the date has passed).

```
// new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
var target = new Date(2014, 0, 30, 12, 30, 0, 0)

function countdown(id, targetDate){
    var today = new Date()
    targetDate.setDate(today.getDate())
    targetDate.setFullYear(today.getFullYear())
    targetDate.setMonth(today.getMonth())
    var diffMillis = targetDate - today
    if (diffMillis >= 0){
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = millisToString(diffMillis)
    }
}

setInterval(function(){countdown('seconds', target)},1000)
```

It uses the javascript date object, so you can literally use any date.

**Updated example to do:**

- format the countdown using hours:minutes:seconds etc
- stop the timer after the date is reached

**Updated:** updated code to override the targetDate to today's date.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kKx7h/5/

Comment: I would be fine with considering another method, however, with this timer my problem is that it's acting as a shipping type timer (you have 5 hours for this order to be shipped today..) repeating everyday, so it's not based off a date/time in the future but rather the same time everyday monday-friday

Comment: Heh, starting coding and checked back to find this :D
http://jsbin.com/ImOcOYAY/1/.. Feel free to use the code - don't feel like making the padding work

Comment: @JonGirard, I've updated the example to set it so that it always uses today's date (but left the time).

Comment: gah.. can't walk away: http://jsbin.com/ImOcOYAY/3/edit. Btw, you can set hours and minutes with Date.setHours

Answer (score 0):

For `4:30PM`, try `var target = 16.5` instead of `var target = 1630;`

Comment: Unfortunately setting .5 doesn't seem to do it

Answer (score 0):

You now need to add another variable for the minutes. We can have target as an object literal rather than declare two variables for time:

```
 var target={hour: 15, minute:30};

if ( (now.getHours() < target.hour) && () now.getMinutes() < target.minute ){
```

Comment: I think this solution is close to working, unfortunatley it still doesn't work though. I was getting an error because of the () so I had to change it to `var target={hour: 16, minute:30};
   if ( (now.getHours() < target.hour) && (now.getMinutes() < target.minute ) ){` but it just produces 00:00:00

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part :-/, you might have other problems in your script; I was answering your question which was to do with setting the time more precisely rather than in hour blocks.